# How to skip ahead in a string search to the index right after the value was found? Python

Tags: python, search

My program has two functions right now.

`get_orf(dna)` that takes a string called dna as input. If the string starts
with the start codon ‘ATG’ then `get_orf` searches in multiples of 3 for any of the stop codons.

If it finds one of them then it returns the ORF (’ATG’ and the sequence until the stop codon).

```
orf_List = []
stopCodons = ["TAG", "TAA", "TGA"]

def get_orf(dna):
    #checks to see if the first three amino acids are ATG
    if dna[:3] == "ATG":

        #if the first three are amino acids, 
        #it checks the dna string in multiples of 3 uisng the range fucntion
        for k in range(0, len(dna), 3):

            #checking for stop codons in the dna string
            if any(s in dna[k:k+3] for s in stopCodons):

                #if a stop codon is found, it returns it
                return dna[0:k]
        #prints No Orf if there are no stop codons found
        else:
            print("No ORF.")

    #prints No Orf if the dna does not start with ATG
    else:
        print("No ATG IN BEGINNING.")
```

and `one_frame(dna)` that takes a DNA string as input.

`one_frame` searches that string from left to right in multiples of three. When
it hits a start codon “ATG" it calls `get_orf` on the slice of the string beginning at that start codon (until the end) to get back an ORF. That ORF is added to a list of ORFs and then the function skips ahead in the DNA string to the point right after the ORF that we just found and starts looking for
the next ORF. This is repeated until we’ve traversed the entire DNA string.

```
def one_frame(dna):

    i = 0
    while i < len(dna):
        for i in range(0, len(dna), 3):

            if "ATG" in dna[i:i+3]:

                newOrf = get_orf(dna[i:])
                orf_List.append(newOrf)



            #i don't know how to skip ahead

    print(orf_List) 
    return(orf_List)
```

When I call `one_frame("ATGCCCATGCCCCCCTAG")`, I have trouble figuring out how to skip ahead to the last index of the ORF that was found so that I may continue my search. Any help?

With this code, it prints out "ATGCCCATGCCCCCCTAG" AND "ATGCCCCCCTAG". The smaller one should not be printed since it is INSIDE of the larger one.

Comment: btw, thanks for the effort writing up the question and including [mcve]. It's really helpful and makes it much easier to understand the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you get rid of `for` loop in `one_frame` and implement it as a `while` loop (looks like you already tried that).

Then you can manually control `i` value and add length of the found ORF to it to skip ahead.

```
def one_frame(dna):
    orf_list = []
    i = 0
    while i < len(dna):
        if "ATG" == dna[i:i+3]:
            new_orf = get_orf(dna[i:])
            if new_orf:
                orf_list.append(new_orf)
                i += len(new_orf)
                continue
        i += 3

    print(orf_list)
    return(orf_list)
```